SwiftUI Keyboard toolbar not visible when the TextField is hosted inside a UIKit SplitViewController
I am hosting a SwiftUI View which contains a TextField and Toolbar to be displayed above the keyboard inside the Detail View of UIKit SplitViewController. When the textfield is pressed, the keyboard is visible but the toolbar is missing. When the app goes from background to foreground the keyboard toolbar is visible. Please help.
Below is the SwiftUI View. Please help. Thanks
struct TestContentView: View {
    @State private var name = "Test"
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Click me!") {
                        print("Clicked")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


Anyone got a solution for the above issue? The keyboard toolbar is visible only when app moves from background to foreground.
